# How to get micrometer prometheus metrics working for Flux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

For `Spring Framework 5.0.1.RELEASE` and `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6` We want to use the [micrometer application monitoring](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/2.0), so wie included:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus')
```

Into our dependency set and create a controller with the following rest endpoints:

```
@RestController
@Timed
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/flux", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/stream+json")
    public Flux<MyItem> getMyItems(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        return this.service.getMyItems(params);
    }
}
```

So we got the `/test` endpoint which is just waiting two seconds and we got the `/test/flux` endpoint which is returning a list of itmes.

Bot requests work. The only difference is that for the `/test` endpoint I get prometheus metrics and for the `/test/flux` endpoint I do not get any metrics:

```
http_server_requests_duration_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/get/test",} 1.0
http_server_requests_duration_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/get/test",} 2.002811046
http_server_requests_duration_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/get/test",} 0.0
```

Do I have to configure something else to get that working for requests which are returning a `Flux` or is `Flux` yet not supported?

Comment: I believe that the webflux metrics are still being completed in micrometer. Follow this issue for details: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoconfiguration of WebFlux endpoints is included in Boot 2 RC2!